# how to calculate difference bewteen each line number like excel in javascript or java

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, excel

I have a given list of data, which contains the following records, the records are for give fiscal year, from jan-decemebr

`Date       order`

```
1/1/10     787668
1/2/10     787789
1/3/10     788031
1/4/10     788240
.............
.............
.............
12/29/10    839832
12/30/10    839965
12/31/10    840238
```

In excel it's easy to get the difference between two given consecutive, date create a formula and drag it and it will display the difference

I have to the same thing in Node.js or Java, is there any Java API or java script, node_module present so that i can just the input as orders and the output will be the difference between two consecutive data, `the sample example`

```
    Order  diff    
    787668  119
    787787  161
    787948  32
    787980  114
    788094  30
```

Answer (score 0):

i have written the following for the Java API

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiffrenceCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("date_column"));

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        List<String> ls = new LinkedList<String>();

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            ls.add(line);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {

            int k = i + 1;
            if (k >= ls.size()) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(ls.get(k))
                    - Integer.valueOf(ls.get(i)));

        }

    }

}
```